# Disable Kendo mvc Multiselect

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I have a kendo multiselect on a page and I want to disable it based on a certain criteria. Is it posible to do that ? If not, could you please tell me a workaround for it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var multiselect = $("#multiselect").data("kendoMultiSelect");
multiselect.enable(false);
```

Docs: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#methods-enable

Comment: But... This will this not _enable_ the drop down? OP wants to _disable_?

Comment: @Sandman Just noticed my mistake, swap true with false. Answer edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to disable it based on a certain criteria

If you want to disable at server-side, you can use ***Enable***. Otherwise, you can use [@Alaa Masoud](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44866474/296861)'s answer to disable at client-side.

*For example,*

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Ids)
    .BindTo(Model.AvailableNames)
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .Enable(Model.IsActive))
```

Comment: .Enable(false) does not seem to do anything. I can still edit the control.